# Set UIView frame equal to the frame of another view from a different superview

Tags: ios, swift, frame

I'm creating UIViews that are in different superviews, but I want to set the frames to be equal to each-other.

[image]

This is what I've tried so far

```
let globalPoint = self.view.convert(subViewOfOuterView.frame.origin, to: nil)
let frame = CGRect(x: globalPoint.x, y: globalPoint.y, width: self.subViewOfOuterView.frame.width, height: self.subViewOfOuterView.frame.height)
subViewOfInnerUIView.frame = frame
```

But my view ends up looking like this

[image]

Comment: Don't mess around with frames. Use autolayout. As long as OuterUIView and InnerUIView have a common superview somewhere up the chain you can simply constrain the edges of the two views to one another

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm using frames because I'm doing animation

Comment: Ok, but you can just animate using constraints.

Comment: @Paulw11 How would I solve this problem using auto layout

Comment: As I said, assuming the two views have a shared parent somewhere in the hierarchy you simply constraint the leading anchor of one view to the other. Same with top, bottom, and trailing anchors

Comment: @Paulw11 I run into more problems trying to implement autolayout into my program, I think I would rather use frames, do you know how to solve this using frames

Comment: @Sam I've updated my answer. Hopefully I got what you wanted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the object names you provided, here is an example that creates a 2nd view, also a UIButton (subViewOfInnerUIView), that will have the same frame as the 1st button (drawButton). Both buttons are subviews of different superviews within the main view. I used a UIButton so I could label the view, but any other subclass of UIView whose frame can be set will also work.

Note that since they have the same frames, aside from having the same size, they also have the same position relative to their superviews.

This should also work even if the objects in question reside in subviews that are several layers deep, or shallow. It should not matter.

The example can be recreated in a single view playground in the latest XCode. Hope this helps!

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view = view

        let subView1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 250, width: 300, height: 300))
        subView1.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(subView1)

        let subView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 50, width: 340, height: 100))
        subView2.backgroundColor = .green
        view.addSubview(subView2)

        let drawButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: subView1.frame.width / 2 - 50, y: 25, width: 150, height: 50))
        drawButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        drawButton.setTitle("DRAW BTN", for: .normal)
        subView1.addSubview(drawButton)

        let subViewOfInnerUIView = UIButton()
        subViewOfInnerUIView.setTitle("DRAW BTN2", for: .normal)
        subViewOfInnerUIView.backgroundColor = .brown
        subView2.addSubview(subViewOfInnerUIView)

        let frame = view.convert(drawButton.frame, to: nil)
        subViewOfInnerUIView.frame = frame
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Here's the updated code for making the two views overlap.  I animated the change so it's clear, and also commented specific frames to try and explain how it was done:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view = view

        let subView1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 250, width: 300, height: 300))
        subView1.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(subView1)

        let subView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 50, width: 340, height: 100))
        subView2.backgroundColor = .green
        view.addSubview(subView2)

        let drawButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: subView1.frame.width / 2 - 50, y: 25, width: 150, height: 50))
        drawButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        drawButton.setTitle("DRAW BTN", for: .normal)
        subView1.addSubview(drawButton)

        let subViewOfInnerUIView = UIButton()
        subViewOfInnerUIView.setTitle("DRAW BTN2", for: .normal)
        subViewOfInnerUIView.backgroundColor = .brown
        subView2.addSubview(subViewOfInnerUIView)

        let frame1 = drawButton.frame
        let frame2 = subView1.convert(drawButton.frame, to: view)
        let frame3 = view.convert(frame2, to: subView2)

        print(frame1) // original drawButton frame in its superview
        print(frame2) // drawButton frame relative to the main view (self.view)
        print(frame3) // drawButton frame relative to subView2 (this is the frame you want)

        subViewOfInnerUIView.frame = view.convert(drawButton.frame, to: nil)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
            subViewOfInnerUIView.frame = frame3
        }, completion: nil)

        subViewOfInnerUIView.frame = frame3


    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

The last line which sets subViewOfInnerUIView.frame to frame3 is basically what you want.  You can probably create a function that does the work of these 3 lines to make it easier (taking the 2 subviews as arguments), although admittedly it may not be so simple if the view hierarchy is deep:

```
    let frame2 = subView1.convert(drawButton.frame, to: view)
    let frame3 = view.convert(frame2, to: subView2)
    subViewOfInnerUIView.frame = view.convert(drawButton.frame, to: nil)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I posted the output from your solution, the two buttons are not overlapping

Comment: @Sam I thought that output was the effect you wanted.  Let me see and make it so that the buttons will overlap.  Should be a quick edit.

Comment: @Sam I've updated my answer.  Hopefully this is the behavior you want :)

Comment: So everything works for this problem, but in my actual program I'm having a problem getting the frames to be equal to each only when the app starts. This is a picture describing it https://imgur.com/a/oB20OFI and this is my project on github https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/set . This only happens when the app starts, and doesn't even happen when a new game is started. The code where I do the stuff discussed here is on line 120 and 131 of ViewController

Comment: Strictly that problem relates to something else, mostly the state of your views and variables being different when the app starts and when you click newGame. I solved your issue by copying your code in this method: @IBAction func newGame(_ sender: UIButton) and moving it to viewDidAppear, to replicate the state of your app when someone clicks newGame, where the bug does not occur. I also removed the updateViewFromModel call in viewDidLoad. I have noticed also that some properties related to views' frames and positions differ at didLoad vs didAppear, and that's why I put the code in the latter.